# Iterating through data frame and comparing

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

So say I have a very simple dataframe like this:

```
  v    h  ptsv  ptsh
PIT   NE    21    28
 GB   KC    31    23 
CHI  HOU    27    20
```

It has the visitor (`v`) and home team (`h`) columns and it has points scored (`ptsv`, `ptsh`) columns. I want to create a new column in the data frame that compares the score and inputs the home team or away teams initials.

I wrote this code:

```
tbl2$win <- rep("x",nrow(tbl2)) <BR>
tbl2$win <- ifelse(tbl2$ptsh > tbl2$ptsv,  tbl2$h, tbl2$v)
```

Instead of printing out the initials, it prints out the number that they would be in alphabetical order. Still new to R.

Answer (score 2):

```
   tbl2$win <- ifelse(tbl2$ptsh > tbl2$ptsv,  tbl2$h, tbl2$v)
```

Your first line of code was not required

Comment: Interesting but I was wondering why it doesn't print to that new column the actual values like "NE", "CHI" etc. it prints out numbers 1:6 because of what I assume is the alphabetical equivalent spot  (levels = CHI, GB, HOU, KC, NE, PIT)

Answer (score 1):

You have `factor` data in your `data.frame`, which will confuse `ifelse`:

```
str(tbl2)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ v   : Factor w/ 3 levels "CHI","GB","PIT": 3 2 1
# $ h   : Factor w/ 3 levels "HOU","KC","NE": 3 2 1
# ...
```

From the `?ifelse` help-page examples:

> ## ifelse() strips attributes
>   ## This is important when working with Dates and factors

Convert those columns with `as.character` first:

```
tbl2[c("v","h")] <- lapply(tbl2[c("v","h")], as.character)
ifelse(tbl2$ptsh > tbl2$ptsv,  tbl2$h, tbl2$v)
#[1] "NE"  "GB"  "CHI"
```